# Cannot select any Redux store object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array of objects (or at least I think it is an array of objects) that I get from an API and store in my Redux store. When I `console.log` it, it appears like this:

```
[{…}]
   0:
      author: 1
      id: 1
      modified: "2020-07-10T20:49:54.046643Z"
      published: "2020-07-10T20:49:54.046597Z"
      subtitle: "Now we have subs too"
      text: "Fricking post title"
      title: "This is a test post"
      __proto__: Object
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
```

When I do a `console.log(typeof postList)`, it returns `object`, and that's my first (side) question: **why object, if it's an array?**

The main question involves accessing this object properties. Below is my functional component code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getPostsList } from '../store/actions/getPostsListAction'

export const MainPost = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   const postsList = useSelector(state => state.postsList)
   console.log(typeof postsList)

   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getPostsList())
   }, [])

   return (
      <div>
         <div>{postsList[0].title}</div>
      </div>
   )
}

export default MainPost
```

When I run it, it returns an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. And so, that's my main question: how can I access any property of this object in Redux store?

Comment: Arrays are type object.  `typeof [] === 'object'` is true.  You can use `instanceof` to check specifically for array: `[] instanceof Array` is true.

Comment: What do the redux devtools say, what actions are dispatched and what are the states? My guess is that you set state.postsList asynchronously so on first render it's an empty array. The typeof array is object and even if you checked correctly (Array.isArray) does not guarantee the array has a first element (state.postList[0]).

Comment: Yes, my axios request to get the `postsList` data is asynchronous. But now I'm very confused, because I thought Redux would "take care" of asynchronous data and update the component when the store changes (or at least is what people say about Redux!) If I cannot render async data because it's async, what would I do? I need to render it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useSelector is async and you can expect the object not to be there for an instant and you need a check to ensure the object is there before you render it. This will fix it:

```
   return (
      <div>
         <div>{postsList && postList[0] && postList[0].title}</div>
      </div>
   )
```

Comment: Got it! Is there a better way to render an asynchronous element? Or this is the "mainstream" way to do it?

Comment: I don't know of a better way. When rendering data that may not be there you have to have a check like this somewhere to make sure it is actually there.